# How can I find what is OID for cpu usage in windows 7?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, snmp, oid

I have a vm with windows 7. I have installed windows snmp agent service.
Then from my pc I have developed a small program in C# to communicate with SNMP agent using [snmpsharpnet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/) and works!

I used some sample OIDs like:

- .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 to get system description
- .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.6. to get number of processes

So my program works and I have correct network connectivity.

```
        string host = "192.168.1.92";
        string community = "public";
        SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp(host, community);

        if (!snmp.Valid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SNMP agent host name/ip address is invalid.");
            return;
        }
        Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, new string[] { ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2" }); 

        if (result == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No results received.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Oid, AsnType>  kvp in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", kvp.Key.ToString(),
                                  SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(kvp.Value.Type),
                                  kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Now I am trying to get cpu load using **.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2** but I doen't work (got info from [here](http://forums.manageengine.com/topic/finding-cpu-mem-utilization-for-windows-system)). I have also installed a Mib Browser (from [ireasoning.com](http://www.ireasoning.com/)) to learn correct OIDs.

My questions are:

- Which is correct OID to get CPU Load from windows 7?
- OID are not common for all systems, aren't them? I mean linux, windows, routers have their own OIDs?
- Where can I find OIDs for windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2** is part of the hrProcessorTable in the HOST-RESOURCES MIB.  Using a tool like Mib Browser, do an SNMP Walk on the table OID, **1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3**.  Or, start on that OID and do an SNMP Next.  If you for example have a dual-core CPU, the processor load for one of the cores may be in an OID like **1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2*.1***.

Comment: My vm has only on cpu. In my Ireasoning MIB browser I went to OID hrProcessorLoad (.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2) and works (it is giving average over last minute). But in my code, snmp.get is returning null

Comment: I'm not super familiar with MIB Browser, but I think there's a raw text output when you do your SNMP calls.  I wonder if it is doing the SNMP Next call for you.

Comment: GetNext worked fine.
Sometimes CPULoad is in .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.7 others in .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.6 so I do a GetNext in the upper level GetNext(".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2") and got it. Thanks.

Comment: SNMP definitely has its quirks.  Glad to hear you found what you were looking for.

Comment: So when you do the GetNext the first one is the total CPU usage? And the other ones are the other cores?